# What are the primary vulnerabilies when developing an http server with node.js

Tags: node.js

The most notable vulnerability I've read about is XSS but as I am developing a node application I want to know what the biggest vulnerabilities are and the best practices in regards to patching them. I am using the http module (stock with node) for handling requests. This is basically what my request handling code is:

```
var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    var urlparse = url.parse(req.url, true);
    if(urlparse.pathname == "api endpoint") {
        //pass POST data into other functions and return those functions' results
    } else if (urlparse.pathname == " another api endpoint") {
        //and so on...
}
```

My main worries:

1. Does user input need to be sanitized when not working with databases?
2. Does user input need to be sanitized when using [node-mysql](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql)?
3. Are there other vulnerabilities not having to do with user input sanitization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything you get from the client has to be treated as untrusted. From the input they give you, to the querystring they use, to the form data they submit, to the url that they call, to the cookies that are transferred should all be treated as untrusted and needs to be validated/sanitized. No amount of client validation is good enough (though that helps the user experience).  Everything has to be validated on the server, regardless of whether or not you use a database. Private session data should be kept on the server with an cookie id reference vs passing the data to itself to the client.

Additionally, everything you display on the client that you don't control 100% must also be treated as untrusted and needs to be properly escaped first. You also need to protect the files that you serve with appropriate permissions to make it harder for them to be compromised if somebody is able to log into your server (once you lose the server, you've lost everything but at least you can make it as difficult as possible).

It's a lot of work, but on the bright side if you are just learning and building a small website you probably won't be on the radar of most of the more sophisticated hackers (they like larger targets than your one server).  As long as you take some basic precautions, lock down your server appropriately with good passwords/ssl and do some basic web hardening you'll be fine.